# Docker image very slow

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build a Prestashop image using Docker Compose, I use this **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: prestashop/prestashop:1.7
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      PS_DOMAIN: localhost
      DB_SERVER: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass123
      MYSQL_DB: prestashop
    dns: 8.8.8.8


  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: prestashop

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: prestashop
      PMA_HOST: mysql
```

But every time I start it, the server does not respond for several minutes (Firefox says "connection was reset"). And once I can eventually access to the webpage, it is very slow.

Is it something that I can solve by changing my docker-compose file ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: When you use a bind mount `volumes: [.:/var/www/html]` to inject content into the container how much is this; just some static assets, or the entire application and framework?  What is your host OS?  (If it's the entire application and its framework, and you're on MacOS or WSL, this is known to be a very slow setup.)

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks ! Yes I really suspect that binding all the CMS (which is what I do) might not be a good idea. My host OS is Windows 10 / WLS2. So I should only bind volumes of interest right ? (like css / Html files that I plan to modify)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `.dockerignore` in your build.

This helps to avoid unnecessarily sending large or sensitive files and directories to the daemon .

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

also check this out for best practices https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/